# ActionScript 3 No Mouse Click When Mouse Moves

Tags: actionscript-3, mobile, mousemove, touch-event, mouseclick-event

I have different elements in a scroller:

```
protected var theScroll:Scroller = new Scroller();
```

Every Element got an EvenetListener:

```
mc1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, showMC, false, 0, true);
```

If a user wants to scroll the elements the EventListener is called and the user can't scroll.

How can I check whether a user wants to scroll or click?

Any ideas?

Best Janine

Answer (score 0):

Set a mouse down flag in your element at the mouse down handler, if that boolean flag is true and you are having a mouse **move** event (check it at mouse move handler) then that means user is trying to drag. Do not forget to reset the flag when mouse goes up. FYI: Flex has a drag event.

Comment: This doesn't work. if(_mouseMove != true){ } We added a mouseMove EventListener and a MouseUp Listener to remove the flag. Now it is only possible to scroll the list and the element never shows up. We develop a mobile app so the device always fires a move event if we touch the display.

Comment: If we use TouchMove event it always shows the element and you can't scroll. The Touch_move is called a little bit too late so the flag isn't set and the element shows up...

Comment: Maybe this can help. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS1ca064e08d7aa93023c59dfc1257b16a3d6-7ffe.html

Comment: We can't find a solution. We played around with angle detecion but this also does not work. The problem is that both elements are dragable. So we can't simply set a flag :-(

Comment: TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, TouchEvent.TOUCH_MOVE,TouchEvent.TOUCH_END,... those do not work?

Comment: **A suggestion**: Do not make the scroll elements draggable, even do not hook events to them individually. Listen to events on the container of the scroll elements, then bind events to individual scroll element when container signals the event (determine the element via coordinate or other way) this way you can understand if move or tap only, since any move on the border of scrollelem1 passing to scrollelem2 will TOUCH_END for scrollelem1, which will worsen the situation.

Comment: We used a click event on the scrollable elements. So now they aren't draggable anymore. The element shows up on the "main screen" and the user could drag it. Thanks a lot for your suggestions. We hope the users can handle and understand this :D